# Invoking Web Services From a Java Client

Tags: java, web-services, containers

I have a simple web app that runs inside Tomcat.  I need to call a web service from this web app and I'm not sure how to go about it.  It seems there are two methods depending on whether you are using a managed or unmanaged environment:

JNDI service lookup (managed)

and

JAX-RPC ServiceFactory (unmanaged)

...So which technique should I use?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to necessarily use those techniques. Assuming you're using Axis as the web services engine and ant as the build tool(http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html), you need to do the following
1) generate the proxy/stub for invoking the web services. This will give you an entry point into calling the webservices
2) provide configuration info for the client -- a .wsdd file
3) know where the WSDL for your webservices is.

BR,
~a

Answer (score -1):

If it is a web-service, why not use apache's [httpclient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/)?